# inverting a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

This is a code that inverts a dictionary but I've faced some troubles in order to understand **the role of each element of code in the defined function invert_dict(dic)**, it would be great if someone breaks it down to me and explains to me the mission of each element.
Thank you.

```
animals = {'Lion':["meet", 1.2 ,'yellow'],'Cat':["milk", 0.3,'white'],'dog':["Dog", 1,'black']}

def invert_dict(dic):
    return {v: d.setdefault(v, []).append(k) or d[v] for d in ({},) for k in dic for v in dic[k]}

print(invert_dict(animals))
```

The output:

```
{'meet': ['Lion'], 1.2: ['Lion'], 'yellow': ['Lion'], 'milk': ['Cat'], 0.3: ['Cat'], 'white': ['Cat'], 'Dog': ['dog'], 1: ['dog'], 'black': ['dog']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a classic use for `defaultdict`

```
animals = {'Lion':["meet", 1.2 ,'yellow'],'Cat':["milk", 0.3,'white'],'dog':["Dog", 1,'black']}

from collections import defaultdict
def invert_dict(d):
    ret = defaultdict(list)
    d = [(v,k) for k, lst in d.items() for v in lst]
    for k,v in d.items():
        ret[k].append(v)
    return dict(ret)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{v: d.setdefault(v, []).append(k) or d[v] for d in ({},) for k in dic for v in dic[k]}
```

Let's break this down from the right side

```
for k in dic for v in dic[k]
```

Uses the dictionary with value as lists `{ k: [v1, v2] }` and extracts the corresponding key as `k` and list of values in `v = [v1, v2]`

```
v: d.setdefault(v, []).append(k) or d[v] for d in ({},)
```

The `for v in dic[k]` loops on the values for each key i.e. `[v1, v2]` and uses a `defaultdict` to identify the value already exists in the resulting dictionary, if it does, it appends the key from the original dictionary to the new resulting inverted dictionary. If not, it assigns the key.

For a sample `{ k: [v1, v2, v3], z: [v1] }`, after each run, the state of the inverted dictionary is as follows:

```
{}
{ v1 : [k] }
{ v1 : [k], v2 : [k] }
{ v1 : [k], v2 : [k], v3: [k] }
{ v1 : [k, z], v2 : [k], v3: [k] }  # because v1 already exists, z is appended
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def invert_dict_exploded(dic):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for key in dic:
        for value in dic[key]:
            d[value].append(key)
    return dict(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to go in order, from the outside to the inside:

- Braces and colon notation
- For loops
- Append *or* value

### Braces

Braces are used in Python to create *a dictionary or a set*. In this case they are used to create a dictionary since we have the {key: value} notation. In this discussion let's call it "the returned dictionary".

### For loops

These for loops are the equivalent of:

```py
for d in ({},):
    for k in dic:
        for v in dic.values():
            ...
```

This is a shorthand notation that comes in handy to create collections quickly. It's normally quite readable when it's not, like in this case, abused.

The `for d in ({},)` is only used to declare a dictionary that will sit there while iterating through the keys and values (because as we see above, it's in the outer-most loop). The dictionary is named `d`.

### Append *or* value

For each key/value pair, we create a new key in the *returned dictionary* by using the colon notation, where the key is actually one of the input values, and then we do two separate things:

1. Append an item in our *d* dictionary, which is always a list
2. Assign the list to the given key

The `k.setdefault(v, [])` bit will set a default value of `[]` if no key `v` is found in the dictionary and then will return that list (the newly created empty list or the list found at that key), which is then used by the `.append(k)` bit to append the key as a value to that list. This takes care of cases where you have items in your input list with the same value, collecting all the keys together for that value, like in:

```py
animals = {'Lion':["meet", 1.2 ,'yellow'],'Cat':["milk", 0.3,'black'],'dog':["Dog", 1,'black']}
```

Where you can see the multiple lists containing the "black" item and will output the following:

```py
{'meet': ['Lion'], 1.2: ['Lion'], 'yellow': ['Lion'], 'milk': ['Cat'], 0.3: ['Cat'], 'black': ['Cat', 'dog'], 'Dog': ['dog'], 1: ['dog']}
```

Notice both "Cat" and "dog" keys are added to the "black" list in the result.

Finally, the *or* part. The `list.append()` function always returns `None` since every function that doesn't return explicitly, automatically returns `None` in Python.

The `or` operator is used to short-circuit the expression. It's written as `A or B` and is to be read as "If A evaluates to a true value, the expression evaluates to A; if A evaluates to a false value, the expression evaluates to B". `None` always evaluates to false in boolean terms, so the expression `d.setdefault(v, []).append(k) or d[v]` always evaluates to `d[v]` but only after executing the `setdefault()` and `append()`.

`v: d.setdefault(v, []).append(k) or d[v]` can therefore be read as:

Create a key `v` in our *returned dictionary*; if `v` is not a key of `d`, set `d[v] = []`; append to `d[v]` the value `k` and set `d[v]` as the value of `v`.